# jQuery: Doing something on a static and dynamically created elements (delegated events)

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I load the page I have some "static" HTML tags with particular class called `.file_item` in a container called `#files_container`. Later on the same page, without refreshing I'm appending (prepending) via Ajax new `.file_item`'s. Simple $.ajax - works fine.

My problem is that then I want to performn an on click event on those elements.

**I KNOW** what's the problem - **I KNOW** how to solve this but I find my approach as extremely ugly. I know about delegated events (http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) and I know that triggering:

```
$('.file_item').click(function() {
    // will work on static elements but won't work on "dynamic" elements appended via Ajax.
});
```

vs.

```
$('#files_container').on('click', '.file_item', function() {
    // won't work on static elements but will work on "dynamic" elements appended via Ajax.
});
```

**Finally my question:** How can I combine those two together so then no matter if `.file_item` did exist when I loaded the page or was appended 15 minutes later via Ajax, my code inside brackets will be executed?

Edit:

Here's how the HTML looks like:

```
<section id="files_container">
    <section class="file_item">file 1</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 2</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 3</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 4</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 5</section>
</section>
```

Additional files will be prepended via Ajax.

```
<section id="files_container">
    <section class="file_item">new one injected via prepend by $.ajax</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 1</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 2</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 3</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 4</section>
    <section class="file_item">file 5</section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the second code snippet you've provided. it will work for static and dynamic elements. Always delegate events when there are static and dynamic elements no need to write two event handlers.  if that code is not working for you there must be something else failing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the static elements are not a descendant of the `files_container` element that is why the delegated handler is not working for it.

So the solution is to find a common parent between the static and dynamic elements and bind the delegated handler to it. Since you have not shared your markup, below I'm binding the handler to the document object which should handle both the cases

```
$(document).on('click', '.file_item', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I updated my question to show you the markup. No rocket science. There will be always just one file_container that will have bunch of file_items. Your solution with binding to document didn't work.

Comment: @slick http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1remk8nh/2/ - in that case your code should work fine

Comment: @slick can you update the fiddle to recreate the case

Comment: Thank you guys. Indeed `on('click'` works on both static and dynamic. I had a different part in JS that was breaking my code. All solved! Thanks again!